# Google AIY Voicekit V1 doesn't respond

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, google-aiy

When running the AIY voice kit "assistant_grpc_demo.py" demo app, it recognizes what I said, but no reply comes from it.

Also, for the "assistant_library_demo.py" demo app, it detects when I say "Ok Google" but doesn't recognize anything I say after it.

Does anyone know how to solve these problems?
Any help or suggestions are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. I finally made it work by flashing an older version of the VoiceKit image. ***[Here](https://github.com/google/aiyprojects-raspbian/releases)*** you can find the older versions:

I used *[VoiceKit Classic Image 2017-09-11](https://github.com/google/aiyprojects-raspbian/releases/tag/voicekit)* and it worked out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it got resolved by following [this](https://github.com/google/aiyprojects-raspbian/issues/447) thread.